# Find all $n\in \mathbb N$ such that $n$ raised to any natural power always contain digits which are odd only.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Find all $n\in \mathbb N$ such that $n$ raised to any natural power always contain
> digits which are odd.

I have never taken a course in number theory and natural numbers so I couldn't solve it. However, upon hit and trials, Here is what I noticed :

1. It can neither be a one digit ( except $n=1$) ,two digit number. Upon squaring we see that they have even number of digits.
2. Three digit numbers from $100$, to $300$ have odd digits. But $400^2$ have even number of digits. Upon some hit and trial, we get that $316=99856$.

However, as pointed in comments, I took the question wrong and hence my observation was invalid.

I am looking for a general but elementary method to solve this. ( Because I don't know much technical number theory). But, all answers are welcome.

Thanks !

Comment: Why don't $1$ and $10$ work?  Or $5$ for that matter...

Comment: @lulu $5^2 = 25$ and $25$ have two digits and two is even. Similarly for $10^4$. For $n=1$ , sorry. I'll add it.

Comment: What you wrote is "always contains odd digits".   I took that to mean that there was always at least one odd digit in $n^k$ for all $k$.  Apparently you meant something else.  Please edit your post to explain your meaning.

Comment: How many questions from UGB did you solve?

Comment: @aqualubix I attempted 5-6 . But gave proper answer for only question - 2. Rest all were partial and hand-waiving answers , which I wrote for hope of some partial marks. What about you friend ?

Comment: I solved $3$ properly. I attempted $2$ others and gave partial answers. I left the rest.

Comment: @aqualubix much better than mine. All the best for good results !

Comment: (Concur with Lulu). Given any number, one of its powers will start with 1. Thus answer is "all integers".  $\quad$  @aqualubix Since it seems like you know this competition, can you clarify the question?

Comment: @CalvinLin The question isn't asking for last digit to be odd. It's saying that the number raised to any power should result in a number which must have an odd **number** of digits.

Comment: @CalvinLin, we are looking for natural $n>1$ such that $n^k$ has an odd number of digits in the usual base $10$ representation for each $k\in\mathbb{N}.$ For example, $n=2$ doesn't work as $2^4$ is $16$ which has an even number of digits. But, $n=100$ works.

Comment: @An_Elephant No, that's not what the question said. It just said "contain odd digits". 1, 3, 5, 7, 9 are odd digits. EG The number 12 contains odd digits (in particular, 1). $\quad$ Can you edit the question?

Comment: @CalvinLin Since you're more sure than me, so I'll edit it.

Comment: @An_Elephant, no, the edit doesn't fix it. The edit says "such that $n$ raised to any natural power always contains digits which are odd". This is not what we want.

Comment: @aqualubix Then what you want ? The number of digits shall be odd or the digits themselves should be odd or something else ? I originally wrote the first one and edited for the second one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(Answering the question for "has an odd digit", based on the current writeup)

Show the following. If you're stuck, state what you've tried.

1. The leading digit of a number $a$ is determined by the fractional part of $ \log_{10} a $. In particular, the leading digit is 1 iff $0 \leq \{ \log_{10} a \} < \log_{10} 2 $.
2. For any $a$, there exists an $n$ such that $ 0 \leq \{ n \log_{10} a \} < \log_{10} 2$.
3. Hence, conclude that this is true for all integers.

---

(Answering the question for "has an odd number of digits", based on the comments.)

Show the following. If you're stuck, state what you've tried.

1. The number of digits in $a$ is $\lfloor \log_{10} a \rfloor +1$.
2. The number of digits in $a^n$ is $\lfloor n \log_{10} a \rfloor +1$
3. Show that if $ \log_{10}a \neq k$ for some even $k$, then there exists $n$ such that $\lfloor n \log_{10} a \rfloor + 1$ is even.
   You could even calculate the first instance of such $n$.
4. Show that if $ \log_{10} a = k$ for some even $k$, then $\lfloor n \log_{10} a \rfloor +1$ is odd for all $n$.
5. Hence, conclude that the only such numbers are $10^k$, where $k$ is even.

Comment: But, $n=10^1$ doesn't work. Here, $1$ is odd, but $10$ has an even number of digits. Neither does $n=10^3,$ since it has $4$ digits.

Comment: @aqualubix Yup, fixed that typo. Sorry, making a bunch of edits to this to figure out how best to present. It should be clear that the answers are (at least) 1, 100, 10000, ...

Comment: yes now it makes sense. OP somehow seems to be confused as to what the question is asking of them. But, during the exam, I arrived at the same answer $(n=10^{2k},k\in\mathbb{N}).$

Comment: @aqualubix It's expected. I'm a usual school student and learnt of JEE in 11th. Hence, number theory and other miscellaneous things were never taught to me. I just filled for ISI after recently knowing of this exam.

Comment: @CalvinLin The results you used are completely new to me as I've never learnt these things. I hope that in future I'll understand your answer after learning these things :) thanks

Comment: @CalvinLin, shouldn't the number of digits in the base $10$ representation of $n$ be $\lfloor \log_{10}(n)\rfloor + 1?$

Comment: @aqualubix Ah yes, fixed.